# Smallest subnormal number in IEEE double precision

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

In IEEE standard for a double precision system, we know that the least exponent for a normal number is 1-1023=-1022, and the representation for 0 is 
(1.00...0)_2 * 2^(0-1023), where the exponent is -1023.

A subnormal number has exponent -1022 and as opposed to a normal number, the leading mantissa is 0. That is, the representation for a subnormal number looks like:
(0.b,...,c)_2 * 2^(-1022), where b,...,c is a series of binary values(i.e., 0 or 1).

I wonder whether the following representation is considered a subnormal number:

> (0.00...0)_2  * 2^(-1022), 
>   where mantissas are all 0 and the exponent is -1022.

This question is raised because the representation above is equal to  0 mathematically, while a subnormal number is different from 0. 
In addition, I tried but did not find a formal definition of a "subnormal number".
If you know where it is defined rigorously, please let me know. Thanks.

PS: What makes me confused is the term "non-zero" used in the definition of a subnormal number. "zero" means 0 mathematically or IEEEly (the representation for 0 in floating point system)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples includes the smallest subnormal, bit-pattern = `0x0000000000000001` representing the value `2^(-1022) * 1`, in case anyone else got here based on the title question and wanted that answer.  (Yes, `0.0` has an all-zero exponent field, so its value calculation works like a subnormal if we don't special case it, but we don't normally call it one.)

Comment: A clearer title might be "is 0.0 a subnormal number?"

Answer (score 3):

A subnormal number is defined in IEEE Std 754™-2008, section 2.1.51, as a non-zero floating point number with magnitude less than the magnitude of that formats smallest normal number.

By definition, zero is neither a normal number nor a subnormal number.

Comment: In the term "non-zero" , does "zero" mean 0 mathematically instead of the representation for 0 in IEEE754 ?

Comment: @booksee I'm not sure what you are asking. Remember that, because of the bias, the most negative exponent is stored as the all zero bit pattern, so a zero is either the all zero bit pattern or the only with only the sign bit on.

Comment: @booksee the number you propose can't be a subnormal number because it's mantissa is 0.

Answer (score 1):

a floating point number with zeroes in the exponent part and zeroes in the mantissa will be a signed 0.

subnormal numbers have a nonzero mantissa.

Comment: Thanks. Just want to make sure, could you provide any reference ?

Comment: quoting [this](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF): "Subnormals, which permit Underflow to be Gradual, are nonzero numbers with an
unnormalized significand n and the same minimal exponent k as is used for 0 ".